# Rotating User-Agents in python web-scraping script for Google Scholar website but still I am not able to get any data(Laravel)

Tags: python, php, laravel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**This is my Python Script**

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

import requests, random

user_agent_list = [
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36',
  'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.18',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/84.0.4316.14',
  'Opera/9.80 (Linux armv7l) Presto/2.12.407 Version/12.51 , D50u-D1-UHD/V1.5.16-UHD (Vizio, D50u-D1, Wireless)',
  'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/42.0.2393.94',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; zh-CN; EML-AL00 Build/HUAWEIEML-AL00) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/57.0.2987.108 baidu.sogo.uc.UCBrowser/11.9.4.974 UWS/2.13.1.48 Mobile Safari/537.36 AliApp(DingTalk/4.5.11) com.alibaba.android.rimet/10487439 Channel/227200 language/zh-CN',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) U2/1.0.0 UCBrowser/9.3.1.344',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 10; en-US; RMX1901 Build/QKQ1.190918.001) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/78.0.3904.108 UCBrowser/13.4.0.1306 Mobile Safari/537.36',
  'UCWEB/2.0 (Java; U; MIDP-2.0; Nokia203/20.37) U2/1.0.0 UCBrowser/8.7.0.218 U2/1.0.0 Mobile'
]

for _ in user_agent_list:
  #Pick a random user agent
  user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)

  #Set the headers 
  headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}


url  = 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=EnegzCwAAAAJ&hl=&view_op=list_works&cstart=0&pagesize=100'

response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gsc_a_t'})

titles = []
for item in table.find_all(class_='gsc_a_at'):
  title = item.text
  titles.append(title)

print(titles)
```

**This is the error I am getting because it is not able to find that classes as it doesn't get the main website in response**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Research
> SPIT\scraper\public\title.py", line 44, in 
> for item in table.find_all(class_='gsc_a_at'): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

**This is my controller**

```
$process = new Process(['python', public_path() . '/title.py'], null, ['SYSTEMROOT' => getenv('SYSTEMROOT'), 'PATH' => getenv("PATH")]);

        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            dd($process->getErrorOutput());
        }

        dd($process->getOutput());
```

**Tried multiple fake-user agents nothing is working for me, Any help would be really appreciated**

Comment: Did you ever check if you get a 200 response from the server? it looks as if you're trying to process to response without validating the request was successful.

Comment: Other websites are working but Google Scholar checks some parameters and if the user is genuine it only then gives all the HTML code from which I want specific data, that's why I used headers of user agents to get into that page and it works on google collab but not in laravel. @Meny Issakov

Comment: Ana, do you get NoneType as a response because you're getting a 200 answer from the URL, but without any data, or do you get another response?
What is the response.status_code value?

Comment: You didn't post the code of titles.py, your fetch code works, but the parser code is missing so it hards to see what's causing the error

Comment: The above python code is my `title.py` and yes I am getting NoneType because in `table` variable I am not able to access that class in laravel because as I said I am not being considered a genuine user by google scholar and that's why I am not getting the whole HTML code @Meny Issakov

Comment: @AnaFernandes I can't reproduce your issue - all the user agents work for me and I get [the same results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TcoU-nhKJp0XcQqAF4SrOQAq32x2mNmTYd9JsTz73PI/edit?usp=sharing) [100 titles] with each of them - would you mind running my [test code](https://pastebin.com/vJTKLXk8) and sharing output csv?

Comment: It returns `""`  nothing @Driftr95

Comment: @AnaFernandes it should be saving a file "user_agents_testLog.csv" [most likely in the same folder as "title.py"]...did the file not get saved?

Comment: Yeah I got that all of them say in **req_status** `429 Too Many Requests` **titles_count** `0`
`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `cherry-ua` library to generate more authentic user agents, it also supports advance filters to generate specific user agents for eg. for windows or macOS or linux, and its very easy to use:

```
from cherry_ua import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
ua.get_random()
```

[cherry-ua](https://pypi.org/project/cherry-ua)